# re-bind jquery dialog/modal

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

Thanks to an earlier help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224717/cant-execute-jquery-post-or-ajax-after-initial-run), re-binding click events work fine now.  However, I can't seem to re-bind the dialog definitions.  Reading from other answers here, it seems the answer lies in using "delegate" but I can't seem to figure it out.  Here's the updated code with the dialog:

```
$('[id^="del"]').live('click', function(){
    var valname = $(this).attr('id').split('del_');
    $.post("delthis.php", {id: ""+valname[1]+""}, function(data) {
            $("#dynamic_section").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});

$('[id^="thismodal"]').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'explode',
    width: '760',
    resizable: false,
    modal: true
});

// Dialog Link
$('[id^="mlink"]').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valname = $(this).attr('id');
    var sname = valname.split("mlink_");
    var modal = "#thismodal" + sname[1];
    $(modal).dialog('open');
    //return false;
});

// html
// loop
<div>
<p>
   <a href='#' id='del_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Delete <?php echo $row['id']; ?></a><br />
  <a href='#' id='mlink_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Show Modal <?php echo $row['id']; ?></a>
  <div id='thismodal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
    This is the modal showing element # <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
  </div>
 </p>
</div>
// end loop
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This SO question helped a lot: [How do I rebind the dialog after it is being rewritten by AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975742/how-do-i-rebind-the-dialog-after-it-is-being-rewritten-by-ajax)

So for my question above, I just created:

```
var initModal = function () { 
    $('[id^="thismodal"]').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'explode',
        width: '760',
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    });
};
```

and called it every time I repopulated the html